# Multiple Generics in a method

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, type-parameter

My main question is if I can bind a generic object two 2 types if the it is extended by e.g. 4 types. I do not really know how to ask this question without an example.

So i created a little example of a simple game in which Warriors or Rangers can equip different type of Weapons(OneHanded, TwoHanded, Melee, Ranged). Every Weapon has two attributes. So the e.g. the Weapon type `Dagger extends Weapon implements OneHanded, Melee`.

Ranger class (can use two-handed, ranged Weapons):

```
    private Weapon weapon;

    public <T extends TwoHanded & Ranged> void equip(T weapon) {
        this.weapon = (Weapon) weapon;
    }
```

Warrior class (can use one-handed, two-handed, melee, ranged weapons):

```
    private Weapon weapon;
    public <T extends OneHanded & Melee & Ranged> void equip(T weapon) { //probably have to do this differently
            this.weapon = (Weapon) weapon;
    }
```

Bow and Dagger class:

```
public class Bow extends Weapon implements TwoHanded, Ranged {}
public class Dagger extends Weapon implements OneHanded, Melee {}
```

```
public void equipTest() {
    ranger.equip(bow);    //works fine
    warrior.equip(dagger); //does not work
}
```

The main problem here is (I think) that I do not know how to implement it that a warrior can equip different weapons with different attributes(e.g. bow(ranged, two-handed) or also dagger(melee, one-handed)) whereas the ranger has only one possibility. How can I workaround this problem?

Comment: just create **two** methods, one for `T extends OneHanded & Melee` and one for `T extends OneHanded & Ranged`. Or just omit the second constraint completely, as `Mellee || Ranged` is always true.

Comment: @HimBromBeere your first solution doesn't really work. The compiler will complain about method clashes since they have same erasure.

Comment: @jrook just what I wanted to write. I cannot really overload methods with same signature. Different Generics don't count.

Comment: This is probably just an example, but using compile-time constraints here is overly limiting. For instance, you couldn't implement features such as drinking a potion that allows you to yield a two-handed sword with only one hand for a few days. The specification pattern is perfectly suited for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code does not compile because `Dagger` does not implement `Ranged`.

I think you mean `Melee` or `Ranged`. This could be written as overloads.

```
<T extends Melee & OneHanded> void equip(T weapon) {
<T extends Ranged & OneHanded> void equip(T weapon) {
```

Note change of order in order for the overload to have distinct erasures. However, it is much better to have **distinct names rather than overload**.

(Also, I'd use a layer of indirection instead of losing the type information with a base type.)

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. But is it possible to do this for all 4 different weapon types? If I try to overload all 4 methods, I cannot do it because they have the same erasure: `<T extends Melee & OneHanded>`, `<T extends Ranged & OneHanded>`, `<T extends Melee & TwoHanded>`and <T extends Ranged & TwoHanded>`

Comment: Use different names for different methods. But if you insist: `<T extends Melee & OneHanded>`, `<T extends OneHanded & Ranged>`, `<T extends TwoHanded & Melee>` and `<T extends Ranged & TwoHanded>`

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by using a layer of indirection here, perhaps with an example?

Answer (score 0):

The other answer directly addresses the issue in the question. As you can see, using this design, the best option for you is to end up with a bunch of `equipXXX()` methods.

An alternative would be to use the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Create abstract `Weapon` and `WeaponDecorator` to allow maximum flexibility for later adding new weapon types.

```
public abstract class Weapon {
...
}

public abstract class WeaponDecorator extends Weapon {
    Weapon _weapon;
    WeaponDecorator(Weapon weapon) {this._weapon = weapon;}
}
```

Convert various weapon types to act as weapon decorators:

```
public class OneHanded extends WeaponDecorator {
    OneHanded(Weapon weapon) {
        super(weapon);
    }
}

public class Melee extends WeaponDecorator {
    Melee(Weapon weapon) {
        super(weapon);
    }
}
```

and remove all generics from the `Warrior` class too:

```
public class Warrior  {
    private Weapon weapon;
    public void equip(Weapon weapon) {
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }
}
```

Now you can simply do:

```
Weapon w = new OneHanded(new Melee(new Dagger()));
Warrior warrior = new Warrior();
warrior.equip(w);
```

Here is a [full example](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns/tree/master/decorator) with code and more explanation.

**EDIT**:

If you choose this solution, the responsibility of checking the validity of selected weapon for a selected hero should also be addressed in run time. For example, this can be added to `Ranger`'s `equip` method:

```
if(weapon.isMelee()) //error (unacceptable)
```

But as the set of rules grow complex, you might want to use other patterns such as [the command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). Still, all of this will be delegated to run time. This is the price that you pay for acquiring more flexibility. Of course, you can also try to acquire some compile-time safety by creating a hierarchy of decorators (similar to what java.io library does). However, this could make the application overly complicated very fast.

In the end, if there are only a few of this combined types (`TwoHanded + Melee`, `OneHanded + Ranged`, etc) it makes sense to go with the other answer and just have a few more `equip` methods and have the safety of compile time type checking.

Comment: It's just that it doesn't cover at all how composition constraints would be implemented, which was the original goal of using types.

Comment: @plalx I edited my answer to address the issue your raised.